# Getting Cake script output when running build.ps1 from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, cakebuild

When you run a cake script using the powershell bootstrapper (build.ps1), you get some detailed console output, which you can configure further using the -Verbosity option.

However, when I am running the script from within an executable (our own CLI, basically), despite having subscribed to all the Powershell datastreams, I am not getting the console output from cake.

Is there a way to fix this?

Powershell code for executing and getting script events:

```
public class PowerShellCommandService: IPowerShellCommandService
{
    public void ExecutePowershellScript(string script)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Executing script: {script}");
        using (var localRunspacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool())
        {
            localRunspacePool.Open();

            using (var engine = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
            {
                engine.RunspacePool = localRunspacePool;
                engine.AddScript(script);
                engine.Streams.Debug.DataAdded += Debug_DataAdded;
                engine.Streams.Information.DataAdded += Information_DataAdded;
                engine.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;
                engine.Streams.Verbose.DataAdded += Verbose_DataAdded;
                var asyncResult = engine.BeginInvoke();

                Console.WriteLine("Starting script from CLI... ");
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                while (!asyncResult.IsCompleted && stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 240000)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                stopwatch.Stop();
                if (stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 240)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Script timed out after {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s. Asking Powershell to stop.");                        
                    engine.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine("Stopped. Script execution aborted..");
                    //engine.BeginStop((test) => Console.WriteLine("Stopped."), state);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Script completed in {stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}s.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void Verbose_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>)
        {
            var collection = sender as PSDataCollection<VerboseRecord>;
            Console.WriteLine(collection[e.Index]);
        }
    }

    private void Debug_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PSDataCollection<DebugRecord>)
        {
            var collection = sender as PSDataCollection<DebugRecord>;
            Console.WriteLine(collection[e.Index]);
        }
    }

    private void Error_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>)
        {
            var collection = sender as PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord>;
            Console.WriteLine(collection[e.Index]);
        }
    }

    private void Information_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PSDataCollection<InformationRecord>)
        {
            var collection = sender as PSDataCollection<InformationRecord>;
            Console.WriteLine(collection[e.Index]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you executing the Powershell script within your executable?

Comment: @devlead I updated the question with the Powershell execution code